# Non-stop voice to text translation for Zoom meetings

Tags: translation, zoom

Any suggestions for continuous voice to text translation for Zoom meetings?

I know that room creator can enable automatic AI interpretation with subtitles, but what if one does not host but just attends a meeting?

For somebody who does not talk much but would like to understand what other talk about.

I know Android SayHi and MS Translate can be used in dialogs but non-stop translation of the meeting voice is problematic, one need always hit that microphone button, it gets tiresome. Google translate and deeple did not impress me much.
I tried a third party translation Plugin yet it require a bot presence which other meeting participants might dislike

Any good apps or other solutions? Preferably free.

A similar topic was [discussed](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34522/non-stop-voice-to-text-translation) many years ago, but perhaps the technology is  now up to the task?

Comment: Although this is close to a duplicate of the question to which you link, because you specifically reference Zoom meetings, I think it is useful to keep this question open too.  Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can try out Hintscribe. Hintscribe is an AI Meeting Assistant and Transcription tool that can transcribe entire system audio so it doesn't need any bot joining the meeting. Transcription is free, additionally it can be integrated with OpenAI's ChatGPT so you can select any part of transcription (or all) and prompt GPT about it.

I'm the founder of this project so if you have any questions feel free to reach out to me directly.

Comment: Hi awasik! Can you please add a link to Hintscribe to your answer? Thanks!